Raspberry Pi CM Global_EN - Automatic reboot when power is available
I´m designing a mainboard for the Raspberry Pi CM and I got stuck at the Global_EN pin. The mainboard should have a function to shutdown the Raspberry Pi as soon as the main power is gone and the Raspberry Pi should reboot automatically when the main power is back. The shutdown is done via a battery backup but I don´t have any idea how I can add the logic for the Global_EN pin properly.
The datasheet writes the following:

A simple idea would be to use the input voltage to pull down the Global_EN pin. But I´m not sure what happens if Global_EN is low all the time.
What is a good way to use this signal to add an automatic reboot?

You can pull GLOBAL_EN low, which prevents the PMIC from running.
If you consult the PMIC data sheet this is documented.
